# Is it possible to pass a php file to html5 audio src attribute?

Tags: php, html, audio, attributes, src

In my php code I have an audio tag with:

```
'<audio src="song.php" />'.$fallback.'</audio>'
```

In "song.php" I tried different things, but nothing worked:

```
include "thesong.mp3";
readfile("thesong.mp3");
echo "thesong.mp3";
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Yes but you have to set the correct content headers in the PHP file.

Comment: Why not just use php to make a list of the songs and to echo the songs src path in it itself? For example, `<audio src="<? echo 'MP3/thesong.mp3'; ?>'.$fallback.'</audio>'; Where I echo the songs, it would be from your list of index songs.

Comment: When you used readfile did you set the proper headers? See the example in the readfile documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'm still trying with header ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following inside your PHP file.

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename="thesong.mp3"');
```

Comment: Thank you Enijar for your quick answer, this is the solution I was looking for. I made two testfiles with minimum code on my local server and it works. Now I have a new problem to get this running on my Joomla Website, but maybe this is another question.

Comment: OK, got it. The filename has to be the complete real path, no URL or relative path.